# How to create a QueryField editable from Admin in Django?

Tags: django

Had some idea using Django : I would like to create content for my website using the admin. But when I'm talking about content I refer to :

- navbar categories
- links (which are attached to a category)
- articles

So far I have been able to do all of this. Nothing really hard, some models, conditions and methods and you're up working.

What is bothering me is that I'd like to create a QueryField in my article model. Use of this last is for customisable content list.

A simple example is a modal showing up the list of all articles published so far. So I created up a Link, my modal is showing up. But how can I tell from my admin that I want it to list all objects from a customized queryset that is, it self, created in the admin as well.

Short : how can I create a models.QueryField() ?

The article model is pretty simple.. :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    lined = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Could you show your article model, A sample? Also, the data that is added via admin/database will reflect in the admin if you register the article via admin

Comment: Here you go, tough I don't understand how it would help my question, i'm looking for something pretty generic. The article model is just supposed to contain the customizable field.

Comment: `The article model is just supposed to contain the customization field.` Then why don't you add a foriegnkey field (another model that stores the custom field data) that you want to make customizable?

Comment: I want it to be generic, it's not just a FK on an object. It's rather a query on whatever you want in the database.

Comment: okay, but, somewhat not clarified with, `But how can I tell from my admin that I want it to list all objects from a customized queryset that is, it self, created in the admin as well.` Need somewhat solid kind of example. :)

Comment: objs = QueryField(); Then in admin I indicates all articles so objs refers to objs = Article.objects.all(); I might want to restrain it from the admin as well (Articles.objects.filter(published=True) for instance. A QueryField in pretty self explanatory I think, it's a model field that contains a query. I don't want it to be a FK since I need to add as much objects as I want. I don't want it to be a ManyToMany as I want it to be generic. Also I want the user to be able to customize it as it fits his needs. Basicly the ORM technology wrapped up in a Model Field.

Comment: I was still looking out an option to achieve it. I have reached a point where I can have a `QueryField` as a custom field, but do you want the admin to show all the objects when the field is set as `Article.objects.all()` or just store the value `Article.objects.all()`?

Comment: Foremost when there is nothing selected I would like being able to do some work on which model to use and what kind of query I can then do. But this is some kind of work ; what have you done ? Can I have a look on it ?

Comment: I will provide the code asap once I get time to do so. :) not finding time for the same :|

Answer (score 1):

By using the effective idea of [Custom Model Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-model-fields/):

```
from django.db import models
import os

class QueryExecutor(object):
    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.qValue = value
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.qValue
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.qValue

class QueryField(models.Field):
    description = "This is a custom field for storing query"
    
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'CharField'
            
    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, QueryExecutor):
            return value
        return QueryExecutor(value)
        
    #def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
    #   return "" + value + ""

class PageDetail(models.Model):
    PAGE_TITLE = (
                  ('HOME','HOME'),
                  ('CONT','CONTACT US'),
                  ('ABOU','ABOUT US'),
    )
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=PAGE_TITLE, default='HOME')
    CustomQuery = QueryField()
    Details = models.TextField()
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Name
```

Here is where you would find similar custom fields already in Django:

1. [Geometry Field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/deed00c0d803d324a3dfdeba52458b6b009c1a90/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py#L12)
2. [Small Field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f8bb8436e533abad563b5235cf0e62e42dbc5f01/tests/field_subclassing/fields.py#L39)

## Note

This is what I could get in the models, that creates a custom field. It adds a field in admin where I can see the field query selection.

It is not completely working, as I did not find time to complete it. I would delete the answer if its not helping you.

That said, I have a feeling, your admin cannot role list of objects in UI if you mention a QueryField as `Article.objects.all()`

Comment: Nice Idea, I think I should hook-up a complete app for this one for easier development, using the admin shall be more tedious that writing few forms and adding functionalities in views. Though it didn't hit me that a simple method would hit the needs. Thank you \o/

Comment: @cp151 Okay, I hope it at least provided some info which I found out. You are welcome